# play mp3 files with safari or chrome in ios or android

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, audio

i try to preload audio html5 tag and then play the files one by one. 
on a desktop computer that seems to work but on my iphone 4 or 5 with safari or chrome browser - the sounds does not play.

my sounds are mp3, but i also tried with mp

this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>




    <script>    
    $(function(){
        banner_array = [];
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis1_1'
        });
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis1_2'
        });
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis2_1'
        });
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis2_2'
        });
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis3_1'
        });
        banner_array.push({
            "audio": 'dis3_2',
        });

        $.each(banner_array,function(a,b){
            setTimeout(function() {$("."+b.audio)[0].play();},25000);
    });
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis1_1"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis1_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis1_2"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis1_2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis2_1"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis2_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis2_2"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis2_2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis3_1"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis3_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    <audio hidden name="media"  class="dis3_2"><source src="/templates/t4807/audio/dis3_2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

any help shall be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not allow for this -

> Note: On iOS, the Web Audio API requires sounds to be triggered from an explicit user action, such as a tap.

The above exert is taken from the [Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH6-SW5)

Comment: thanks for the ios. but do you why it does not play in android browser?

Comment: You're welcome. When you say "android browser", if you're referring to Google's Chrome application running on an iPhone then the same still applies.

Comment: no, i mean the default browser on an anroid base device